# Indefinite integrals, where the integrand has a different variable than the "dx" portion

Tags: calculus

How could we solve an expression such as: $$\int2ue^udx$$

Would some chain-rule like method need to be used, or would be treat the integrand here as some constant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a dependence of the integrand on $x$? Otherwise, the integrand is just a constant

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really all that meaningful in it's current form. Unless $u$ has some kind of $x$ dependence then

$$\int ue^u dx=ue^u \int dx=ue^u(x+c)$$